# Rotating or scaling cameraView or opponentView in Quickblox isn't working on Android

Tags: android, video, chat, quickblox

When trying to rotate or scale the cameraView or the opponentView in the [Sample-videochat-android](http://quickblox.com/developers/Sample-videochat-android) I get a black view instead.
I tried

```
android:rotation="90"
```

And I also tried flipping the view using

```
android:scaleX="-1"
```

None of the above methods is working. Any suggestions?

Comment: which android version are you using ? because these options are only available as of api 14 or something

Comment: The version am using is 19 so that's not the issue